# Convergence in $L^p$ preserves density

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, alternative-proof

Let $p \in [1, \infty]$. Let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence of probability density functions (p.d.f.) in $L^p (\mathbb R^d)$. Then there is $f \in L^p(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_{L^p} \to 0$. Convergence in $L^p$ implies pointwise convergence of a sub-sequence. Then $f \ge 0$. I want to verify that $f$ is indeed a p.d.f. It remains to prove that $\int f =1$. I use the following theorem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> *Theorem 4.9.* Let $\left(f_n\right)$ be a sequence in $L^p$ and let $f \in L^p$ be such that $\left\|f_n-f\right\|_p$ $\rightarrow 0$. Then, there exist a subsequence $\left(f_{n_k}\right)$ and a function $h \in L^p$ such that
>
> - (a) $f_{n_k}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ a.e. on $\Omega$,
> - (b) $\left|f_{n_k}(x)\right| \leq h(x) \quad \forall k$, a.e. on $\Omega$.

Let $(f_{n_k})_k$ be the sequence and $h$ the function given by above theorem. By [Fatou lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272096/a-detailed-proof-of-fatou-s-lemma),
$$
\int \liminf_k f_{n_k} \le \liminf_k \int f_{n_k} \le \limsup_k \int f_{n_k} \le \int \limsup_k f_{n_k}.
$$

Then
$$
\int f \le 1 \le \int f.
$$

This completes the proof.

---

Of course, the gist of above approach is the existence of the "upper bound" function $h$.

> Is there an alternative proof assuming that we don't know *Theorem 4.9(b)*?

Comment: Do you really use the existence of a dominating $L^p$ function $h$? I think you could just use the fact that convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence in measure/probability, which implies the existence of a sub-sequence converging almost everywhere.

Comment: @homieo'morphic I used the [reverse Fatou lemma](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fatou%27s_lemma#Reverse_Fatou_lemma) which requires a dominating function.

Comment: Your dominating function need to be in $L^1$, which it is not in general...

Comment: For $f$ to be a pdf, the sequence of the probability measures determined by $f_{n}$ need to be tight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is not true. Take
$$
f_n = \chi_{[0,n]}n^{-1}.
$$
Then $\int_{\mathbb R} f_n= 1$ and
$$
\|f_n\|_{L^p}^p = n \cdot n^{-p} \to0
$$
for all $p>1$.